# Installation of Electronjs app with osquery

Tags: javascript, electron, osquery

I am new to electron and I want to build electron installer for all platform (mac, linux, windows, etc) which I am able to do.

This electron app would use `osquery` to grab some information from the user system.

So I want to install and run `osquery`, before installing my `electon` build in user machine.

Tried -- I've tried including .sh file in extraFiles(build - package.json) which contain installation command and that file will be executed in electon/main js file.

But I am unable to install `osquery` and my electron build in one go.

I want user to install only my `elctron` build app and rest software(`osquery`) must be installed in the same process of installation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Electron, but I'm fairly knowledgable about osquery.

I'm not sure what you're trying, but I would not recommend invoking the osquery installer from this. If possible, I think it would probably be better to include the bare osquery binary. You should only need the binary itself, the other things are optional.

There are side question about how you're using osquery -- while you can invoke it with a `--json` argument, the usual way to work is to communicate over a thrift socket.

Answer (score 0):

Check this Osquery installation guides, hope they help you:

- [MacOs](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/install-macos/)
- [Linux](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/install-linux/)
- [Windows](https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/install-windows/)

Comment: I am able to install and run osquery (osqueryi) in mac.

Comment: My problem is to install osquery on client machine through my electron app installer

Comment: As client is non technical person thats why osquery should be installed through button click, or installer wizard of electron